# why dont glut cubes or spheres show up?

Tags: c, opengl

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
//glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
//  glVertex3f(-0.5,-0.5,0.0);
//  glVertex3f(0.5,0.0,0.0);
//  glVertex3f(0.0,0.5,0.0);
//glEnd();




glutSolidSphere(200,10,10);

glutSwapBuffers();
```

the triangle shows up but not the sphere
why?
I just get a black window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your radius is probably too big and you are culling back faces.

```
glutSolidSphere(1,10,10);
```

Glut is close-sourced and unmaintained. Consider something else, like SDL.

Comment: his view matrix is probably set up so he is close to the origin looking down the -ve z axis, so he is probably inside his sphere, and like you said, culling backfaces.

Comment: There's FreeGLUT and OpenGLUT, both open source and maintained. Also I don't consider SDL being a ideal OpenGL framework. I'd go with GLFW.